# Android: how add opacity on ImageButton click?

Tags: android, listener, opacity, imagebutton

I thought to use OnTouchListener and tracking down and up events, setting then an alpha value, but I have to add this listener to all ImageButtons (they are really a lot). I wonder if there is a shortcut to achieve this result.

Comment: you want to set the opacity of the button that was clicked or when the user click on some button, the opacity of all the buttons is change?

Comment: When user clicks the button I want to add opacity, and when the user release it the opacity will get the original value

Answer (score 0):

In case that when user click on button and this cause to change the opacity of that button you can do:

In your `xml file` on button declaration add this line:

```
android:onClick = "clickMethod"
```

and in the `java file` you need to implement the clickMethod,

```
public void clickMethod(View view)
{
  // change opacity
}
```

so, if you want to do the same process(change button opacity) for each button, so in the xml file
for each button add the line

```
android:onClick="clickMethod"
```

Comment: Where I have to put clickMethod? Inside each activity?

Comment: no, lets say you have layout called MainLayout.xml with 3 buttons, so in this layout for each button you need to add the line - android:onClick="clickMethod", now in the java file related to this xml file, you should add the clickMethod..

Comment: so for each activity there is a different method.. because it should to be related to the buttons on the layout

Comment: My whole code in quite big, I've wrote in the end of the activity the function clickMethod exactly as above, and inside a button inside the associated layout the android:onClick doing cut&paste

Answer (score 0):

If you want to give users better expirince when clicking ImageButton, I recommend you to use selection drawable as the background of your ImageButtons. It gives better user experience, then setting opacity while performing click and it’s really easy to achieve.

First you need to create in your **drawable** folder file with name f.e. **image_button_selection.xml**. In which you should define:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/your_focused_background_drawable" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/your_pressed_background_drawable " />
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

You should also put into drawable two png with alpha channel that will be displayed on focused button and pressed button. In this example they should be named respectively **your_focused_background_drawable** and **your_pressed_background_drawable**.
When you do this you should in every use of your ImageButton in xml use following statement:

> android:background="@drawable/image_button_selection"